# i cant configure the ip adress and subnetmask ,i only have one router "1941" and 2 pc's

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands, packet-tracer, interface

the command line is this :

```
Router0(config-if)#ip adress 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

the error message is :

```
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Comment: What is the interface you are trying to configure?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the full router configuration, and include the full error message.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled "address".

Using the tab-completion feature on most devices usually helps with spelling errors :)